# Shutdown mongos for upgrade

Tags: mongodb

I am upgrading a mongo sharded cluster, and am in the first step of replacing the mongos process. Can I just kill this process or is there a safer way to shut it down before replacing it?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shutdown/

Comment: I don't want to shut down mongo completely. Only the mongos process.

Comment: `shutdown` will shutdown the Mongo instance and kill the process. You can then restart it later.

Comment: Correct, however, it's a sharded cluster. I don't want to shutdown the instance now. My issue is with safely shutting down the mongos process so I can replace the binary with the newer version. This is a production environment and so I am doing this for 0 downtime.

Comment: The mongo instance **IS** the process - they are not two separate things. If you kill the process, you kill the db instance. If you want the DB instance running, it means you want the process running too.

Comment: No, mongoS process, is the routing service. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongos/ The mongod processes are the mongo instances, and in particular, the shardservers and the config servers. Those get replaced later in the upgrade process, for which shutdown is used. This is explained in depth here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/#upgrading

Comment: Running shutdown against your mongos will only kill the mongos process.

Comment: You can't run shutdown against mongos. I don't believe it is an option. From this link,  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongos/, it is not listed with options, whereas with http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/, it is listed. If I'm wrong, can you give me the exact command to shutdown mongos? To be run in the mongo shell or terminal?

Answer (score 2):

It is the answer.  But may be you misunderstood.  You cannot shutdown mongos from command line, but you have to logon to the shell.  Here is the result I am trying on my own:

```
$ mongo --port 27077 (please replace with your own port on mongos instance)

**mongos**> db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs:30})
shutdown command only works with the admin database; try 'use admin'
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.shutdownServer({timeoutSecs:30})
2015-02-27T12:53:54.408+0800 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
**server should be down...**
2015-02-27T12:53:54.410+0800 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27077 (127.0.0.1) failed
2015-02-27T12:53:54.410+0800 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27077, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-02-27T12:53:54.410+0800 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27077 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27077 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
2015-02-27T12:53:54.413+0800 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27077 (127.0.0.1) failed
2015-02-27T12:53:54.413+0800 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27077, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-02-27T12:53:54.413+0800 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27077 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27077 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>
```

Try to run "top" or "htop" to display all processes running on your computer.  You shall see the "mongos" process has gone.  Read the log file.  Here is the last two lines of my log:

```
2015-02-27T12:53:54.406+0800 [conn1] terminating, shutdown command received
2015-02-27T12:53:54.406+0800 [conn1] dbexit: shutdown called rc:0 shutdown called
```

And here is the link of my testing script:

https://github.com/babycaseny/QuickStart/blob/master/StartShard.sh

Note that you have to replace the "localhost" in the mongod/mongos command with the hostname of your computer, or you will not be able to config your shards.

See also this one:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/TQLlRI6HG1M

In case you need a command line to do the work, here is one:

mongo admin --port portnumber --eval "db.shutdownServer()"

Notice that you have to run the command in localhost.